# Why is ItemSearch in Amazon's Product Advertising API returning invalid XML?

Tags: amazon-product-api

The Amazon Product Advertising API appears to be fatally buggy and I'm wondering if it's just me, and if there's any work around for this apparent bug.

When I present the following parameters to the Product Advertising API:

```
<Arguments>
    <Argument Name="Operation" Value="ItemSearch"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="Service" Value="AWSECommerceService"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="Signature"
        Value="<omitted>"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="Manufacturer" Value="Leg Avenue"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="AssociateTag" Value="<omitted>"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="Version" Value="2009-03-31"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="AWSAccessKeyId" Value="<omitted>"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="Timestamp" Value="2012-10-18T15:49:10Z"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="ResponseGroup" Value="ItemAttributes,SalesRank"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="SearchIndex" Value="Apparel"></Argument>
</Arguments>
```

I get back a whole bunch of XML, part of which contains a clear and significant bug:

```
<Publisher>Rubies/Publisher>
```

Note the missing proper close tag for the `<Publisher>` element.  As you might expect, this causes any XML parser to blow up.

I don't see any easy work around for this.  I searched around a bit and did not find anyone else reporting the same problem, which I find kind of surprising given the severity of this issue.  It basically makes the entire API useless.

I'm sure I'm missing something - the API can't be this buggy.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Can anyone else confirm whether this is a bug?

[Edit] This appears to be intermittent.

Answer (score 1):

If you make too many requests to the Amazon Product API in a row you get throttled. This can make debugging issues frustrating. If the problem is intermittent and you can get the information you expect from the API and your code given different parameters then perhaps there is bad data in Amazon's Product API database or you should wait a day and see if you're getting throttled.

If you're getting throttled you don't get any data instead an error code of some sort, it has been a while since I debugged some issues, [my code works](http://www.muschamp.ca/Muskie/webMashups.html), perhaps you can adapt it.